# how to disable keyboard on debian 9 with shortcut?

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, cat

I want to know if it's possible to configure Debian 9 to dedicate one key on the keyboard to disable the the rest of the keyboard. I'm trying to watch something and my cat keeps walking on the keyboard. I already gave up trying to keep her out of the notebook so it would be nice if the computer didn't respond to that.

Comment: You can cobble something together: `xbindkeys` or your window manager can process specific keys/key combinations. `xinput --float` can disable the complete keyboard by removing it from the `Virtual core keyboard`. The tricky part is re-enabling it, because after floating the keyboard, you need the XINPUT extension to read keys from it. Would a mouseclick to re-enable it also do?

Comment: I want to, but can't, remove the `cat` tag from this!

Comment: `xtrlock` is a minimal X display lock program, which doesn't obscure the screen. It may be useful for you.